# PHP Date function is not working correctly in Ver 5.3.0

Tags: php, date

I am using a date function `echo date ('Y');` which results in the following error message.

Warning: date() [function.date]: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone    settings.

Is this anything to do with my php.ini page? What change I need to make in php.ini in order to make this code working?

Comment: It clearly says what you are supposed to do in the Warning message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make that warning go away, you either need to set your timezone with this function:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

or set this in your php.ini:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.configuration.php#ini.date.timezone

---

**Update**
From the comment below, valid timezones here:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

Comment: Also, list of valid timezones is [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)

Comment: +1. To be noted, this is something that was introduced by version 5.3 of PHP. Doesn't happen on previous versions.

Comment: @Ben - It says since PHP 5.1.0 on php.net, but it is definitely worth pointing out.  Thanks!

Comment: @afuzzyllama. Yes, the methods are available since 5.1+. what I meant is that the warning for not having set a default timezone is since 5.3

Answer (score 1):

Set the timezone to the one you want

```
// example
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
```

See the list of [valid timezones](http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)